# Using tensorflow-gpu in Arch Linux. Problem installing cudnn6 with cuda 8

Tags: arch-linux

Apparently tensorflow needs cudnn6 to use the gpu. I have cuda 8 and cudnn5 and 7 but not 6. I get this error whenever I try to import tensorflow after installing tensorflow-gpu: ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have cuda-8.0.61-2 installed from the repositories.

So I got cudnn6 from here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cudnn6/

And tried make -si but I get: error: target not found: cuda-8.0

Anyone having the same problem? How could I fix this?

Comment: That's a broken PKGBUILD, the depend should be something like `cuda >=8.0` If you read the comments, there is an allegedly working PKGBUILD pasted there.

Comment: @jasonwryan: Why don’t you post that as an answer?

Comment: @G-Man because it is one of those problems "that can't be reproduced..." There is no value in having it legitimised with an answer.

Comment: @jasonwryan Oh didn't see that comment. Thank you!